# how to make right full width line

Tags: jquery, css, html

i make step wise number but there is some problem in responsive, that is when we make top red line in small screen horizontal scroll bar is come up.

please see, click on this link:- [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bharat_negi/43oazqab/)

```html
<div class="container">
  <br><br>
  <div class="col-md-8">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="career-area">
          <div class="top-border"></div>
          <div class="car-Circle1">
            <i><b>01</b></i>
          </div>

          <div class="car-Circle2">
            <i><b>02</b></i>
          </div>

          <div class="car-Circle3">
            <i><b>03</b></i>
          </div>

          <div class="car-Circle4">
            <i><b>04</b></i>
          </div>

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The horizontal scrollbar  can be removed by setting the overflow of `.top-border` to `hidden`:

```
.career-area .top-border {
    width: 100%;
    border-radius: 50px 0px 0px 0px;
    border-top: solid 19px #cc3053;
    border-left: solid 19px #cc3053;
    height: 145px;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
    overflow: hidden;
```

Answer (score 0):

There I try to redesign it and suggest the following code for your help.
1. If you `.top-border` in `.career-area` use following code.

```
.career-area .top-border:after {
    content: "";
    border-top: solid 19px #cc3053;
    top: -19px;
    width: 100%;
    right: calc(100px - 100%);
    /* position: absolute; */
}
```

2. If you `.top-border` in `.container` use following code.

```
.container
{
    overflow: hidden;
}
.career-area .top-border:after {
    content: "";
    border-top: solid 19px #cc3053;
    top: -19px;
    width: 100%;
    right: calc(1px - 100%);
    position: absolute; 
}
```

2. If you `.top-border` in screen width use following code.

`html,body{  overflow: hidden; }`

```
   .career-area .top-border:after {
        content: "";
        border-top: solid 19px #cc3053;
        top: -19px;
        width: 100%;
        right: calc(1px - 100%);
        position: absolute; 
    }
```

This code only hides your total width not inherit the parent hight and overflow hidden hide the overflow border.